# JTabbedPane Tab Title Leaves Padding when font is changed

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm writing a Custom `BasicTabbedPaneUI` I have overrided `paintText` and have changed the fontSize inside it, But that leaves unwanted extra padding to the right of the tab.

[image]

as you can see the padding is fairly big, I would like it to be the same padding as the left side. So this is my code

```
import sun.swing.SwingUtilities2;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;
import java.awt.*;

public class UITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        jTabbedPane.add(new JPanel(), "This is a test title");
        jTabbedPane.add(new JPanel(), "This is also a test title");
        jTabbedPane.setUI(new LynxTabbedPane());
        jFrame.setContentPane(jTabbedPane);
        jFrame.setSize(300, 100);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class LynxTabbedPane extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

        @Override
        protected void paintText(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Font font, FontMetrics metrics, int tabIndex, String title, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {

            Font myFont = new Font(font.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 10);
            g.setFont(myFont);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane,
                    g, title,
                    tabPane.getDisplayedMnemonicIndexAt(tabIndex),
                    textRect.x, metrics.getAscent() + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I would have assumed I need to calculate the tabWidth so I tried to override it and substract 5 from but, But it did not changed to it so now I am clueless.

```
        @Override
        protected int calculateTabWidth(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, FontMetrics metrics) {
            return super.calculateTabWidth(tabPlacement, tabIndex, metrics) - 5;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `setFont` on the `JTabbedPane` Object since it automatically handles the size the tab has to be

```
    Font myFont = new Font(tabbedPane.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, 10);
    tabbedPane.setFont(myFont);
```

Answer (score -1):

The implementation was good but looks like when you pass arguments to paintText method, i sense the title is having extra space at the end. Try title.trim() to remove extra spaces and check the behavior

Comment: trim.trim(); had no effect on the padding, Can you compile the code your self and try it?

Comment: sure i will try and let you know

Comment: My guess is that the font size change does not re-adjust the tab width, But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: May I know which editor you are using for writing your code.